# Unusual form of FOR statement in C++

Tags: c++, for-loop

I was going through [this C++ tutorial](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/arrays/) on arrays and encountered an unusual way of writing `for` statement (See the second loop: `for (int elem : myarray)`):

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
  int myarray[3] = {10,20,30};

  for (int i=0; i<3; ++i)
    ++myarray[i];

  for (int elem : myarray)
    cout << elem << '\n';
}
```

Can someone please explain this way of writing `for` loop? I guess it would print each element of `myarray` one by one but what is the general syntax for this way of writing `for` statement? In what scenarios can it be used?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a foreach loop as opposed to a normal for loop that you've used before and it iterates through the entire array.

This is used when you don't have to (or want to) know the particular index of the array and are only concerned with the value of the elements.

The general syntax is for(**type** x : array) where type is the type of the array (and the elements in it), x is the variable that represents the particular element of the array.

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreach_loop#C.2B.2B) also has an article on foreach loops with examples in different languages.

Answer (score 2):

It should be a *range-based for loop*: http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/control/